# Facebook PHP SDK - Exception - Provide an access token

Tags: php, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to add a "Login with Facebook" option to this website. 
I have attached two relevant code snippets here; most of my code comes from the Facebook developer page.

1. Javascript function - Used along with the FB-SDK that stores a cookie.

   ```
   logInWithFacebook = function() {
       FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {      
               $.ajax({
                   url: "addUser.php",               
                   type: "post",
                   success : function() {
                       redirectTo('dashboard.php');
               },
               error : function() {
               }
       });
   }
   ```
2. PHP Script - Takes the access token and gets the response.

   ```
   <?php
       session_start();
       require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
       $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
           'app_id' => '<entered app id>',
           'app_secret' => '<and secret key>',
           'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
       ]);
       $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
       try {
           $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
           // echo $accessToken;
           // Line - 1
           $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email',$accessToken);
       }
   // CATCHING EXCEPTIONS FOLLOWED BY MORE CODE
   ```

The problem is that this code works as required when in my localhost. However, when I add it to the server, I get the following caught exception every time.

> Facebook SDK returned an error: You must provide an access token.

Also, on echoing the accessToken in the script, I get the same long string as I do when I echo in localhost. So I guess that means the cookie is being stored properly and the access token is available.

As the code works well in the local host, I am not sure how to proceed with debugging.

I tried this as well, replaced the `// Line - 1` with `$helper->getAccessToken()`. In that case I get this.

> Graph Error : This authorization code has been used

1. What are the possible reasons, if any for such a thing to occur? Where something works locally but not when online.
2. How do we go about fixing it?
3. Any mistakes in my current code or a possible solution to my current issue? I am almost sure that it is something very silly or elementary but I am not able to figure it out.